# react native memo or usememo without arrow function possible?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to use memo or useMemo without arrow func. Is that possible ? Because arrow function creates are new instance and I want it to avoid.

```
import React, { memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const Shopping_cart = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const RenderItem = useMemo(({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    )
  }, [datas]);
  return (
    <FlatList 
      data={datas}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item.product_id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <RenderItem item={item} />}
    />
  )
};
```

This without arrow ? Anyone has an idea ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `useCallback` hook for this.
You can read more about it in the official React documentation: [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

```
import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const Shopping_cart = ({ datas, onPressSetting }) => {
  const RenderItem = useCallback(({item}) => {
    return (
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
    )
  }, [datas]);
  return (
    <FlatList 
      data={datas}
      keyExtractor={item => item.item.product_id}
      renderItem={RenderItem}
    />
  )
};
```